# R - Manually Adding Intercept to glmnet Ridge Regression

Tags: r, ridge-regression, glmnet, intercept

Is there a way to manually add an intercept term manually into the `glmnet` function of `R` rather than using the built-in intercept feature? I tried adding a column of ones to my `x` matrix, making it a 29279x493 matrix, and then ran

`lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,alpha=0,intercept=FALSE,standardize=FALSE)
ridge=glmnet(x=x,y=y,family=c("gaussian"),alpha=0,intercept=FALSE,standardize=FALSE)`

but the coefficient of the variable that I had added to correspond to the intercept term equaled 0 for every lambda value. I also tried running

`lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,alpha=0,intercept=FALSE,standardize=FALSE,penalty.factor=penalty)
ridge=glmnet(x=x,y=y,family=c("gaussian"),alpha=0,intercept=FALSE,standardize=FALSE,penalty.factor=penalty)`

where `penalty` is a 493x1 matrix of ones, except for the value corresponding to the intercept variable, which is set to 0. This code also results in a 0 value for the intercept term for all lambda values. Has anyone had success manually inputting an intercept term into `glmnet`?

Comment: I confirm I have the same issue. I would alternatively like to be able to change the penalty for the intercept -- I have a unit conversion issue where the L2 norm should weight the intercept differently than the slope.